# Get list of documents inside different collections with Firestore in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of users with different portfolios. Each portfolio has the same properties but also a collection of investments. It'd be something like this:

```
Map user = {
  "name": "John",
  "portfolios": [ // collection
    {
      "title": "My portfolio 1",
      "investments": [ // collection
        {"title": "My investment 1.2"},
        {"title": "My investment 1.2"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "My portfolio 2",
      "investments": [ // collection
        {"title": "My investment 2.1"},
        {"title": "My investment 2.2"},
        {"title": "My investment 2.3"}
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

To get my portfolios I do something like this:

```
Future getMyPortfolios() async {
    final userId = await authService.getUserId();
    final portfolios = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .document(userId)
        .collection('portfolios')
        .getDocuments();
    return portfolios.documents;
  }
```

But this only returns the portfolios with their titles, not the inner collection with the investments.

I could make another call with these IDs, but I was wondering if there is a quicker way and get everything from that particular user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no faster option.  You will need a separate query to get the documents in any other collection, even if they are subcollections.  Firestore queries are always "shallow".  There are no "deep" queries that get nested documents in subcollections.

Comment: I have to consider that I will use a free account (at least for now). If I need to get user, portfolios and investments, these are 3 separate queries. I could move these 2 collections to normal objects/arrays inside the user directly and avoid these extra call for each user

Comment: Using two additional queries will not result in significant billing increase.  You are charged per document read, not per query performed (unless that query yields 0 documents - in that case you are charged only a single read).  Please consult the pricing documentation: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing

Comment: Also I will point out that storing arrays that can grow unbounded will run into the limit of 1MB per document. At that point, your app will be broken as you will no longer be able to add data.

Comment: is not the same query performed and document read? When I write something I'll have to do it 3 times anyway

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand that question.

Comment: Based on that info I have a write limitation. If I need to modify my user and his investments I need to modify 2 collections instead of 1.
Also you mentioned that there is no limitation in terms of queries but on that link it says that there is a max or reads. Is not that the same thing?

Comment: It sounds like you have a new question that's not really related to the one you originally asked.  I suggest you post a new question an explain the new problem you're running into, along with the code that helps illustrate what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: It's the same question. The way I structure my data depends on this limitation. If the user wants to modify the name of his portfolio and also of one his investments this will do 2x updates and my write limits would be half of it

Comment: If I read the first question correctly, you're asking about how to get documents from multiple collections in one query (not possible at all).  It sounds like your new question is about how to structure data for some reason.  I'd suggest posing your new issue as a new question so we can better understand what problem you're running into.

Comment: Ah ok, yeah, makes sense to me