# Firebase free account limitations using Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Based on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59955680/get-list-of-documents-inside-different-collections-with-firestore-in-flutter/59957119#59957119) and on [this pricing list](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/pricing) I have the next one:

What's the point of using collections when we have a limitation for reads, writes and deletes **per** document?

I have a collection with 2 different collections inside, would I increase everything x3?

Would it be better for moving everything to the first collection as a single document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Firestore pricing for reading ONE document is neither function of the collection (or sub-collection) containing the document nor function of the sub-collection(s) contained by the document.

As you can read in the SO answer/question you refer to, "Firestore queries are always 'shallow'", meaning that when you read a document, you pay for the document read but you don't pay at all for the documents that are in its sub-collection(s).

---

It's worth noting that the concept of sub-collection can be a bit "misleading".

Let's take an example: Imagine a `doc1` document under the `col1` collection

```
col1/doc1/
```

and another one `subDoc1` under the `subCol1` (sub-)collection

```
col1/doc1/subCol1/subDoc1
```

Actually, from a technical perspective, these two collections (`col1` & `subCol1`) **are not at all relating to each other**. They just share a part of their path but nothing else. One side effect of this is that if you delete a document, its sub-collection(s) still exist.

---

So, to answer your questions:

> I have a collection with 2 different collections inside, would I
>   increase everything x3?

It depends on what you exactly read. If you only read documents from the first (parent) collection, you will only pay for these document reads. You will only pay for the documents contained in the two sub-collections if you build two extra queries to read the documents in these 2 sub-collections. Again, you just have to consider these three (sub-)collections as totally independent and therefore you pay for each document you read in each of those collections.

---

> Would it be better moving everything to the first collection as a
>   single document

It really depends on your data model and on the queries you plan to execute. It is totally possible to "move everything in a single document", but you should take care of some limitations, in particular, the maximum size for a document which is 1 MiB.

Also, if your data model contains some complex **hierarchical data** it may be much easier to organize this data using sub-collections within documents instead of using nested objects or arrays in one document. For example, querying documents through data contained in Arrays has some [limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any).

Again, there isn't a "one single truth": it all depends on your specific case. Note that, in the NoSQL world, your data model should be mainly designed in the light of the queries you plan to execute, without hesitating to denormalize data.

Comment: That's a complete answer Renaud ;)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. 
Most of the time I'd have to read documents from each collection but knowing those limitations I think I have no choice here, I'd have to go with different collections I guess.
Thanks again